# Estimate/speedup huge table self-join on mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a huge table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `messageline` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quoteLevel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `messageDetails_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK2F5B707BF7C835B8` (`messageDetails_id`),
  KEY `hash_idx` (`hash`),
  KEY `quote_level_idx` (`quoteLevel`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK2F5B707BF7C835B8` FOREIGN KEY (`messageDetails_id`) REFERENCES `messagedetails` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=401798068 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

I need to find duplicate lines this way:

```
create table foundline AS
select ml.messagedetails_id, ml.hash, ml.quotelevel
from messageline ml,
     messageline ml1
where ml1.hash = ml.hash
  and ml1.messagedetails_id!=ml.messagedetails_id
```

But this request is working >1 day already. This is too long. Few hours would be ok. How can I speed this up? Thanx.

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref           | rows      | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ml    | ALL  | hash_idx      | NULL     | NULL    | NULL          | 401798409 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ml1   | ref  | hash_idx      | hash_idx | 9       | skryb.ml.hash |         1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Did you fix your problem with given answers?

Comment: yes, done something like your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your duplicates like this

```
SELECT messagedetails_id, COUNT(*) c
FROM messageline ml
GROUP BY messagedetails_id HAVING c > 1;
```

If it is still too long, add a condition to split the request on an indexed field :

```
WHERE messagedetails_id < 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it required to do this solely with SQL? Because for such a number of records you would be better off to break this down into 2 steps:

1. First run the following query

   ```
    CREATE TABLE duplicate_hashes
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT hash, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
      COUNT(DISTINCT messagedetails_id) AS cnt_message_details,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT messagedetails_id) as messagedetails_ids
      FROM messageline GROUP BY hash ORDER BY NULL HAVING cnt > 1
    ) tmp 
    WHERE cnt > cnt_message_details
   ```

   This will give you the duplicate IDs for each hash and since you have an index on the *hash* field grouping by will be relatively fast. Now, by counting distinct *messagedetails_id* values and comparing you implicitly fulfill the requirement for different *messagedetails_id*

   ```
    where ml1.hash = ml.hash
    and ml1.messagedetails_id!=ml.messagedetails_id
   ```
2. Use a script to check each record of the duplicate_hashes table